Django stopped updating static files
Django does not upload static files
Hey guys, I am head to you because I have a problem I can’t fix. I am on localhost and Django does not apply modifications I have made on static files, although the file is changed.
So to start here what I have done so far:

clearing browsers caches
rebooting the server
step 1&2 of best answer: stackoverflow.com/questions/27911070/django-wont-refresh-staticfiles
changing browser
deleting pycache files

Nothing seems to work, if you had an explanation on how to fix this but mostly WHY this happens, would be so nice ! 
PS:
I refer to my script in template's end:
    <script type="module" src= "{% static 'homepage/APICalls.js' %}?version=1"></script>
{% endblock content %}

URL with 200 code returning outdated code:
[06/May/2024 15:48:20] "GET /statico/homepage/APICalls.js?version=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 1987

Static files settings:
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

File structure:
C:.
│   db.sqlite3
│   manage.py
│
├───homepage
│   │   admin.py
│   │   apps.py
│   │   credentials.py
│   │   get_jahia_json.py
│   │   models.py
│   │   permissions.py
│   │   serializers.py
│   │   setter.json
│   │   tests.py
│   │   views.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───migrations
│   │   │   
│   │   │
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   │           
│   │
│   ├───static
│   │   └───homepage
│   │           add-icon.svg
│   │           APICalls.js
│   │           comparison_page.css
│   │           content_menu.css
│   │           custom.css
│   │           functions.js
│   │           modifications_page.css
│   │           module_page.css
│   │           module_table.css
│   │           navbar.css
│   │           Neo_Sans_Pro_Bold.woff2
│   │           Plateformepage.css
│   │           responsive.css
│   │           responsive_module.css
│   │           responsive_navbar.css
│   │           responsive_plateforme.css
│   │           Roboto-Regular.woff2
│   │           searchbar.css
│   │           toggle.css
│   │           toggles.js
│   │           unicorn.css
│   │
│   ├───templates
│   │   └───homepage
│   │           all_modifs.html
│   │           base_test.html
│   │           comparison_page.html
│   │           homepage.html
│   │           homepage_test.html
│   │           module_page.html
│   │           Plateformes.json
│   │           plateforme_page.html
│   │           _modal.html
│   │           _modif.html
│   │           _module.html
│   │           _Plateforme_bloc.html
│   │           _Plateforme_bloc_test.html
│   │           _toggle.html
│   │           _version.html
│   │
│   └───__pycache__
│          
│
├───module_monitoring
│   │   asgi.py
│   │   settings.py
│   │   urls.py
│   │   wsgi.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   └───__pycache__
│           settings.cpython-310.pyc
│           urls.cpython-310.pyc
│           wsgi.cpython-310.pyc
│           __init__.cpython-310.pyc
│
└───static
    ├───admin
    │   ├───css
    │   │   │  
    │   │   │
    │   │   └───vendor
    │   │       └───select2
    │   │               
    │   │
    │   ├───img
    │   │   │   
    │   │   │
    │   │   └───gis
    │   │           
    │   └───js
    │       │   
    │       │
    │       ├───admin
    │       │      
    │       │
    │       └───vendor
    │           ├───jquery
    │           │      
    │           │
    │           ├───select2
    │           │   │   
    │           │   │
    │           │   └───i18n
    │           │           
    │           │
    │           └───xregexp
    │                   
    │
    ├───homepage
    │       add-icon.svg
    │       APICalls.js
    │       comparison_page.css
    │       content_menu.css
    │       custom.css
    │       functions.js
    │       modifications_page.css
    │       module_page.css
    │       module_table.css
    │       navbar.css
    │       Neo_Sans_Pro_Bold.woff2
    │       Plateformepage.css
    │       responsive.css
    │       responsive_module.css
    │       responsive_navbar.css
    │       responsive_plateforme.css
    │       Roboto-Regular.woff2
    │       searchbar.css
    │       toggle.css
    │       toggles.js
    │       unicorn.css
    │
    └───rest_framework
        ├───css
        │
        │
        ├───docs
        │   ├───css
        │   │       
        │   │
        │   ├───img
        │   │      
        │   │
        │   └───js
        │           
        │
        ├───fonts
        │       
        │
        ├───img
        │       
        │
        └───js


Have you performed collect static?

Yes I did but it just bring back my files to the state they were in when django stopped updating

Show your folder structure, settings related to static files, template part where you refer to a static file and example of specific url which returns old version of static file.

Note, there is something strange in your log: "GET /statico/ != STATIC_URL
In homepage app you have unusual folder structure: homepage/templates/homepage is the recommended structure for templates, but for static files you don't need extra subfolder /homepage under homepage/static. Move files from homepage/static/homepage to homepage/static, run collectstatic once again.
